# c++: can I use .find function to look for multiple elements in a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character, linear-equation

c++: can I use .find function to look for multiple characters in a string
ex: looking for + and - in an array of linear equations

Comment: Not clear. Looking for multiple instances of + or -? Or do you want to know when both exist? Next to each other or separate? Give examples of what should pass and what should fail in your search.

Comment: Don't ask questions that can be answered "yes" or "no".

Comment: I want to cut the equation into terms so i want to look for both of them at the same time can i use the .find function or is there another way?

Comment: If you want to tokenize it you might be better using `std::regex` and friends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Extracting symbols/variables of an analytical mathematical expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997788/c-extracting-symbols-variables-of-an-analytical-mathematical-expression)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it:

```
auto it = std::find_if( str.begin(), str.end(), [](char c){
    return c == '+' || c == '-';
} );
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

You could also use std::strpbrk, which searches for one or several separators in a string.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strpbrk

As per your comment you want to tokenize the string, std::strtok will do the job:

```
char *token = std::strtok( input, "+-" );
while( token != nullptr )
{
    token = std::strtok( NULL, "+-" );
}
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok

warning: the above code is not thread safe.